# Modified method with new condition

Tags: android, methods, kotlin

I have a next method:

```
fun getTimeFromLastPinInput(): Long {
    return DateTime.now().millis - PreferenceRepository.getLastPinInputTime()
}
```

I want to add a next condition:

```
if (DateTime.now().millis >= PreferenceRepository.getLastPinInputTime())
```

How i can modified my method correct?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Should the function return what it does only when the condition is true? If so, what should happen otherwise?

Comment: @hotkey To be honest, I find it difficult to answer this question, the main task was to add this condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the idea is that the result is meaningless when the condition is false, then you can transform the function to return a [nullable value (`Long?`)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#nullable-types-and-non-null-types), and return `null` in that case:

```
fun getTimeFromLastPinInput(): Long? {
    val now = DateTime.now().millis
    val lastPinInputTime = PreferenceRepository.getLastPinInputTime()
    return if (now >= lastPinInputTime) now - lastPinInputTime else null
}
```

Comment: Or you could simply check whether the value is negative outside the method, no extra code required.